# Implementing a sql constructor which takes a query, where condition, order by and join condition and construct a revised query

Tags: join, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause, sql-order-by

I'm trying to implement a query builder that has the capability to construct SQL query with dynamic where conditions, join condition and order by clauses.

Tried below approaches

1. Appending the conditions manually - since the SQL queries are complex and may involve CTEs / combined queries this will lead to syntax errors.
2. Splitting the query, adding dynamic conditions and later joining.
   In this I tried a regex approach and a sql parser approach. Regex solves few but not working for complex queries. SQL parser - used jsql parser which cannot parse CTEs and medium-complex queries.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Sample code tried below

```
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(query);

    if (statement instanceof Select select) {
      SelectBody selectBody = select.getSelectBody();

      if (selectBody instanceof PlainSelect plainSelect) {
        List<SelectItem> selectItems = plainSelect.getSelectItems();
        if (selectItems != null) {
          StringBuilder selectStatement = new StringBuilder();
          for (SelectItem selectItem : selectItems) {
            selectStatement.append(selectItem.toString()).append(", ");
          }
          components.setSelectStatement(selectStatement.substring(0, selectStatement.length() - 2).trim());
        }

        FromItem fromItem = plainSelect.getFromItem();
        if (fromItem != null) {
          components.setFromStatement(fromItem.toString());
        }

        extractClauses(plainSelect.getWhere(), components.getWhereClauses());
        extractClauses(plainSelect.getOrderByElements(), components.getOrderBys());
        extractClauses(plainSelect.getGroupBy(), components.getGroupBys());
      } else if (selectBody instanceof SetOperationList) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Set operations not supported in this implementation.");
      } else if (selectBody instanceof WithItem) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Common Table Expressions not supported in this implementation.");
      }
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only SELECT statements are supported in this implementation.");
    }
```